# Why won't my error div update?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, css

I'm working on a php program that uses form validation. I left the "errorMessage" div blank in order to update it upon an invalid entry.

Below is the html/bootstrap code.

```
<div class="container">

<large><h1>Get in touch!</h1></large>

<div class="alert alert-success" role="alert" id="successMessage"></div>

<div id="errorMessage"></div>

<form method="post">

<div class="form-group">

    <label for="email">Email address</label>

    <input type="email" class="form-control" id="email" placeholder="Enter email" name="email">

    <small class="form-text text-muted">We'll never share your email with anyone else</small>

</div>

<div class="form-group">

    <label for="subject">Subject</label>

    <input type="text" class="form-control" id="subject" name="subject">

</div>

<div class="form-group">

    <label for="question">What would you like to ask us?</label>

    <textarea type="text" class="form-control" id="question" name="question" rows="3"></textarea>

</div>

<button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary" id="submitButton">Submit</button>
```

Below is my Jquery/Javascript code. This is intended to check for an invalid entry and to put error text in the blank div.

```
<script type="text/javascript">

    $("form").submit(function (e) {


        e.preventDefault();

        var error= "";
        var fieldsMissing = "";
        var successMessage = "";

        if($("#subject").val() == "") {
            error += "<p>The subject field is missing</p>";
        }

        $("#errorMessage").html(error);

        }
    });
```

Comment: Remove } after $("#errorMessage").html(error); Otherwise, your code is invalid and thus produces exception in browser.

Comment: Fixed it. Thank you.